# Ant GET task and proxy

Tags: java, windows, ant, proxy, task

How to use [Ant's GET task](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3agEPrUXO8CvoJ%3aant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html+ant+get&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=firefox-a&source=www.google.com)  with proxy?

I only see there username and password, but there is no proxy host :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key bit in the [`get`task docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html) is:

> **Proxies**. Since Apache Ant 1.7.0, Ant
>   running on Java1.5 or later can use
>   the proxy settings of the operating
>   system if enabled with the -autoproxy
>   option. There is also the 'setproxy'
>   task for earlier Java versions. With
>   proxies turned on,  requests
>   against localhost may not work as
>   expected, if the request is relayed to
>   the proxy.

So you can use the [`setproxy` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/setproxy.html) for older versions of Ant, or see the docs on [proxy config](http://ant.apache.org/manual/proxy.html):

```
<setproxy proxyhost="firewall" proxyport="81"/>
```

*(The username and password attributes of the `get`task are for the remote system, not for intermediate proxies.)*

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Running java 1.8 and ant 1.7.1. How do I enable proxy, need to connect to maven to get some jar files within a build process?

Comment: Cool, `ant dist -autoproxy` works great and doesn't require changing the settings file

Answer (score 1):

In my case (in **Windows cmdline**) the only option that actual worked is to precede the call to ant with a set of definitions. 
Note that they should not be included in double quotes:

> set ANT_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=`proxy.address` -Dhttp.proxyPort=`proxy.port`

with `proxy.address` and `proxy.port` replaced by the actual values of course...

I am including this option here because I have also tried the  attribute but in a project downloaded from the web I could not locate where to put it! The build files for the project where already prepared and ant get was used but it did not work behind a proxy.